# Conditional Formatting based on percentage increase

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to make cells in column E have a red fill if it's value is greater than that of the cell next to it in column D by 10% or more. He is a screenshot if it helps:

https://gyazo.com/8506c9626d217cda68d73da47004ea0a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please select ColumnE and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(E1<>"",E1>=1.1*D1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK.